# how to fix " PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found "?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-livewire

when i run "php artisan jetstream:install livewire"  I get this error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in H:\xampp\htdocs\tadavom123\bootstrap\app.php:14
```

i try to fix it with this codes but not working :

```
composer update
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload 
composer update --no-scripts
```

my composer version is : 2
php version : 7.3.10
laravel version: 8

Comment: i tried this .. but not work .. and i remove the vendor and install again but  it not work again..

Comment: run `php artisan jetstream:install` then try `php artisan livewire`

Comment: i encountered this problem after all artisan cmd  :/  ..  Even when  i run  this cmd 
"php artisan --h"

Comment: then add your `composer.json` file code

Answer (score 0):

in my case, you have to make sure that you write that code in folder that you want to run. In other hand, you need have a library php5-curl installed in your system, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl
```

this curl have to be same with your php version. good luck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31249926)